# iOS LaunchScreen.storyboard change font at run time of App

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, launch-screen, xcode11.3

I am using Xcode 11.3.1 and My current app is in Objective c.

I was using Launch Image earlier and Now, I have moved to LaunchScreen.storyboard. When I select "LaunchScreen.storyboard" as my Launch Screen, App custom Font stop working.

I have set custom font in "Main.storyboard" and Even on some controller I have set custom font using code (UIFont) class.

When I check in "Main.storyboard", all controller have custom font, but at run time it changed and it looks like it using system font (not sure for this, but font is not custom which I set in storyboard).

I have read, If we use "LaunchScreen.storyboard" then custom font will not work on "LaunchScreen.storyboard", but I am using custom font in code and "Main.storyboard".

I am not sure why all fonts are changed, Can anyone know and help me to use custom font?

Edit:
I have verified in Build Phase, font is available there and I have try to print them as well from App Delegate, it is printing font in console as well.

Comment: I think this is bag in Interface Builder, try update to 11.4.1

Comment: I've run in to a similar bug like this. Try adding an invisible label to the LaunchScreen.storyboard where you set you custom font. Then try to set it in code in your view controller for your Main.storyboard. Really weird workaround but that worked for me.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Thank you for the reply, If nothing works then sure I will go with your solution.

Comment: @Groot Thank you for the reply, Ok, sure I will try and let you know.

Comment: @Groot it didn't work for me.